# OneWay data binding on Run.Text behaves like OneTime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my C# / WPF / .NET 4.5 application I have two `Run`s in a `TextBlock` in a `Button`. One of them has data binding on its `Text` property.

```
<Button x:Name="EditorCommandButton" Margin="10" Padding="5" Height="30" Click="EditorCommandButton_Click">
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="&#xE144;"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Command, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource commandConverter}}" />
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Initially, the `Button` appears like so:

[image]

When I update the bound `Command` property on the associated object...

```
private void EditorSetCommand_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    MyType g = (MyType)TheEditor.DataContext;
    Key k = e.Key;
    g.Command.Add(e.Key);
    RemoveHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)EditorSetCommand_KeyDown);
}
```

...its appearance does not change.

When I reset the data context of its parent...

```
MyType g = (MyType)TheEditor.DataContext;
TheEditor.DataContext = null;
TheEditor.DataContext = g;
```

...it updates:

[image]

Essentially I have a `OneWay` data binding behaving like `OneTime`. How do I fix this behavior?

**EDIT:**

The `myType` class:

```
public class MyType : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    // ...

    private ObservableCollection<Key> _command;

    public ObservableCollection<Key> Command {
        get { return _command; }
        set {
            _command = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Command");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

The converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ObservableCollection<Key>), typeof(string))]
public class CommandConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        ObservableCollection<Key> c = (ObservableCollection<Key>)value;
        if (c.Count == 0) return "";
        else return " " + string.Join("+", c);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Implementation of `MyType` with Command property, is it an `ObservableCollection` ?

Comment: @NovitchiS I have added it above. `MyType` has other observable properties also, and they work properly.

Comment: My guess that since it is a collection you need a collection changed notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that your `Text` property does not get updated because the biding `Source` does not trigger a `PropertyChanged` notification. When you make a call to `g.Command.Add(e.Key);` you are not changing the collection instance and your `OnPropertyChanged("Command");` does not get executed. Even though the `ObservableCollection` raises a `CollectionChanged` event, the `Run` element is not listening to it and does not update it's Text property.

To get a fast an ugly solution you could change your `KeyDown` eventhandler to:

```
    private void EditorSetCommand_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MyType g = (MyType)TheEditor.DataContext;
        Key k = e.Key;
        g.Command.Add(e.Key);
        g.Command = g.Command;
        RemoveHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)EditorSetCommand_KeyDown);
    }
```

If you would like a more elegant solution below is how i would have implemented this.

I would lose the converter and change the `ViewModel` class to create all the data the view needs to display:

```
public class MyType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Key> _command = new ObservableCollection<Key>();
    private string _commandsString = String.Empty;

    public ObservableCollection<Key> Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }

    public string CommandsString
    {
        get { return _commandsString; }
        set 
        { 
            _commandsString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CommandsString");
        }
    }

    public MyType()
    {
        _command.CollectionChanged += _command_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void _command_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_command.Count == 0)
            CommandsString = String.Empty;
        else
            CommandsString = " " + string.Join("+", _command);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

In `XAML` you bind to `CommandsString` `String` property:

```
 <Run Text="{Binding CommandsString, Mode=OneWay}" />
```